# How to get particular activity within the range on specific date and time in custom excel calendar

Tags: excel

I am using an excel sheet which I have design looks like an excel calendar. The Outlook of this sheet is as under.
[image]

The 1 is representing the Time which I am getting from system using =time() function, while the No.2 is the date which I am getting from system using today(). I have written the formula using if for range C4:D21 which is working good. The formula is as under.

```
=IF(AND($C$3=K8,B4=K7),C4,IF(AND($C$3=K8,B5=K7),C5,IF(AND($C$3=K8,B6=K7),C6,IF(AND($C$3=K8,B7=K7),C7,IF(AND($C$3=K8,B8=K7),C8,IF(AND($C$3=K8,B9=K7),C9,IF(AND($C$3=K8,B10=K7),C10,IF(AND($C$3=K8,B11=K7),C11,IF(AND($C$3=K8,B12=K7),C12,IF(AND($C$3=K8,B13=K7),C13,IF(AND($C$3=K8,B14=K7),C14,IF(AND($C$3=K8,B15=K7),C15,IF(AND($C$3=K8,B16=K7),C16,IF(AND($C$3=K8,B17=K7),C17,IF(AND($C$3=K8,B18=K7),C18,IF(AND($C$3=K8,B19=K7),C19,IF(AND($C$3=K8,B20=K7),C20,IF(AND($C$3=K8,B21=K7),C21,IF(AND($D$3=K8,B4=K7),D4,IF(AND($D$3=K8,B5=K7),D5,IF(AND($D$3=K8,B6=K7),D6,IF(AND($D$3=K8,B7=K7),D7,IF(AND($D$3=K8,B8=K7),D8,IF(AND($D$3=K8,B9=K7),D9,IF(AND($D$3=K8,B10=K7),D10,IF(AND($D$3=K8,B11=K7),D11,IF(AND($D$3=K8,B12=K7),D12,IF(AND($D$3=K8,B13=K7),D13,IF(AND($D$3=K8,B14=K7),D14,IF(AND($D$3=K8,B15=K7),D15,IF(AND($D$3=K8,B16=K7),D16,IF(AND($D$3=K8,B17=K7),D17,IF(AND($D$3=K8,B18=K7),D18,IF(AND($D$3=K8,B19=K7),D19,IF(AND($D$3=K8,B20=K7),D20,IF(AND($D$3=K8,B21=K7),D21))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

This is a too long function which is only working for two columns I want to know the formula which will match the running time and date within the row date C3:I3 and time B4:B21 and then populate only concerned cell value within the K4 Cell where "False" is written. This formula is working good but I want to a shorter one. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula.

```
=INDEX(C4:G11,XMATCH(K7,B4:B11,-1,1),MATCH(K8,C3:G3,0))
```

Here `XMATCH()` parameter `[match_mode]` `-1` means search next smaller time if time is not exactly same as `Column B`.

Comment: thanks I tried it but it is not working. I tried it with a new date and time. but it is not working.

Comment: Not working means what? Not giving any result or incorrect result? What would your result as per your screenshot.

Comment: It is not giving any result the error is #Name?

Comment: Which version of excel do you have?

Comment: its Office 2016 64-bit

Comment: Then you do not have `XMATCH()`.  Give a try to`=INDEX(C4:G11,MATCH(K7,B4:B11,1),MATCH(K8,C3:G3,0))`